# Order of output values when select one field from table. SQL server

Tags: select, field, clustered-index

In what order will the field values be displayed for "select field from table".
Table is a clustered index
Anything or as in the table?
it looks like in the table. But I would like to know for sure
Does it matter in this case the table is a clustered index or not?

Comment: **Fields** implies columns but, from your question, I assume you are interested in the row order. If you want a specifc order for the columns, make sure you specify the columns in order, within the select statement `select firstcol, secondcol, thirdcol from t;` if you want a specific order of the rows, it is best to specify the order, e.g.: `select firstcol, secondcol, thirdcol from t order by firstcol desc`

Answer (score 0):

Without an explicit `ORDER BY` - there's no defined / reliable ordering.

Relational database are **inherently unordered** - so you **cannot** rely on any ordering - regardless of whether that table has a clustered index or not - **UNLESS** you explicitly specify what ordering you need by using `ORDER BY` .....